# how to install and config fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, dell, fingerprint-reader

I have use **dell-vostro 3578** then i was install *fprintd* . but i can't use my fingureprinte not working.

**$ lsusb**

#### output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:00a6 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader 
Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5689 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

## i have use this command:

```
$ fprintd-entroll
```

### output:

```
 Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

i don't know this output error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is not supported yet.

The following link informs it isn't supported up to 5.19 kernel version: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:138a-00a6

Comment: thanks for sharing this imformation!